# Outlook inbox default by date

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Can I change the inbox settings to show incoming mail sorted by "date" received and not "from" as a default setting?  I seemed to have done something that has changed this and cant get it back?

Comment: Just right click on "Arrange by: From" and change it?

Answer (score 2):

When you click on a field heading in Outlook (From, Received, Subject, etc) it will sort by that field.  Clicking it a 2nd time will sort the same column in reverse order.

By default, Outlook will remember the sort settings you last used until you change them again.  Sort settings are by folder, so if you change your Inbox to sort by date, it won't mean your Sent Items folder will sort that way automatically.

Comment: It seems you need to double click the "arrange by" option (to, from date etc) and then it sets it.  To change you can double click another choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that by clicking on the fieldname and sorting on Date (latest messages first).  Once done, it will remain, until you reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the select the "Arrange By -> Restore to Defaults" to arrange the mail based on Date Received.
Other way to achieve the same is by right click and Restore to Defaults or by Using view menu in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I love answering questions from 4 years ago ;)

I had this problem, and after days of pulling my hair out, discovered what my problem was.  Hopefully it solves someone else's issue too.

I noticed that I accidentally chose to "group by subject."   look in the top left corner of your inbox -  you might see a little box with the word "from."  Right click that and choose "do not group by this field"

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook 2010 I had this issue. What fixed the issue is changing the view settings under "Change View".  I changed it to "Sent To" then changed it back to "Compact".  Not sure why that would have worked but it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shutdown with the Inbox folder set as "from", this will be the default as you move around the folder structure and then return to the Inbox.

To set it back, go to the Inbox, change to you preferred ordering ("Date" for me) and then restart Outlook.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This kinda covers the same ground that's been beat to death in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook 365, go to **View** (top menu) >> **View Settings**.

Then the "**Advanced View Settings**" dialog comes up.

Click on **Reset Current View**
Click on **OK**

Comment: It says sort by 'from' is the default, so resetting would bring it back to the same default.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by going to advanced view settings, columns and then moving received above from.